# Add EditText by button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button, buttonclick

How i can dynamically add new `EditText` by the method `onClick` from `Button`? I have already an `EditText`but i'd like to add other `EditText`on the same layout. Also, the `EditText` must have the same name with counter++

Comment: `the EditText must have the same name with counter`??? Maybe the same id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EditText edText = new EditText(this);
            edText .setId("");
            edText .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    1f));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use LayoutInflater. It's the way on Android SDK to do that things...

See this complete tutorial to understand how to use LayoutInflater: http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/android-layoutinflater-turorial.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText edtNew = new EditText(this);
    edtNew.setId("edtNew"+"parentLayoutName".getChildCount()+1); // "edtNew" is prefix name EditText id , "parentLayoutName" Where you add EitText
    edtNew.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    "parentLayoutName".addView(edtNew);
}
```